# mRemoteNG monitoring the clipboard constantly?

Tags: passwords, trojan, clipboard

Using mRemoteNG 1.75.7012.16814 and Password Depot 11 on Windows 10.

**The issue**: If mRemoteNG is running, and I copy a password from Password Depot to the clipboard, I get this message from Password Depot:

[image]

- I went through the settings of mRemoteNG, cannot find any "disable clipboard monitoring"
- When I installed mRemoteNG, Virustotal said the installer is clean.
- I uploaded the mRemoteNG.exe to Virustotal now, it said 100% clean.

**The Question**: anybody knows, is this a normal behaviour of mRemoteNG?

Or this is normal, since maybe the mRemoteNG.exe isn't a signed/trusted binary? If I right click on the .exe and "Digital Signatures", there is one, clicking on "Details" for it, then "View Certificate", then "Certification Path", I can see a "This certificate is OK."

Answer (score 1):

mRemoteNG has to view the clipboard, as it synchronizes it to the remote host. This is intended and normal behavior for remote desktop software, when you configure it to do clipboard mirroring.